# iOS UITableView numberOfRowsInSection BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm calling the `numberOfRowsInSection` method of the `UITableView` delegate inside of the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but it gives me a **Bad Access Error**:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    NSLog(@"number of rows in section: %i", [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]);
    ...
}
```

Can anybody tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: You should show us what you do at `...` since this might be relevant. For example do you actually return a value. Not doing this might lead to BAD ACCESS too.

Comment: ca u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667986/ios-uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-in-tableview-heightforrowatindexpath-give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an actual value here. So instead of calling `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]]` simply do the same thing again.

In order not to duplicate your code you could create a helper method which you can call in both places, namely, your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and the `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
- (int) myNumberOfRowsMethod{
    // Here you would usually have some underlying model 
    return [self.myContactsOrWhateverArray count];
}
```

Comment: ca u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667986/ios-uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-in-tableview-heightforrowatindexpath-give

Answer (score 2):

You are calling an delegate method.

When you call this method, it'll invoke the related delegates method like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` etc.

It'll cause an **infinite loop** that's why it's crashing.

Comment: ca u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667986/ios-uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-in-tableview-heightforrowatindexpath-give

Answer (score 1):

That's normal.. In that moment your `UITableView` is being created. You shouldn't call methods related to your `UITableView`, before it has been build. You should rely in other mechanism to get the height of your Cells.

Comment: ca u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667986/ios-uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-in-tableview-heightforrowatindexpath-give

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
```

You should be calling

```
[self numberOfRowsInSection:section];
```

Comment: Again with the downvote and no comment!? This works and is a hell of a lot easier than the selected answer. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah. This works and I don't know what's with the downvote. I was calling `[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: section];` and using `[self tableView: self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: section];` solved the problem. Thanks :)